# How do I query for all the nodes between two nodes in a tree?

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-trees, hierarchical-query, transitive-closure-table

I have a hierarchical database strucutre, e.g. columns `ID` and `PARENT_ID` defined for each row, with the top level rows having a `NULL PARENT_ID`.

I have all the relationships from this table flattened into another table, e.g. if there were three records in a single hierarchy of grandparent, parent, grandchild, there would be 3 records:

```
**ANCESTOR, DESCENDANT**
grantparent, parent
grandparent, grandchild
parent, grandchild
```

Rather than execute a hierarchical query to determine that the grandchild is a descendant of the grandparent I can simply check for the existence of a `(grandparent, grandchild)` record in this flattened table.

My question is, using this flattened table, how can I most efficiently return all records which are between two nodes.  Using the example, with `grandparent` and `grandchild` as my parameters, how can I get back the `(grandparent, parent)` record.

I do not want to use a hierarchical query to solve this... I'm wondering if it's possible to do this without any joins.

Comment: Presumably your real hierarchies are not limited to three levels?

Comment: @Renderln, does your flattened table *only* include Ancestor and Descendant columns, or are there other columns (such as number of generations/levels) included? Also, can there be multiple ways to link one descendant to the same ancestor?

Comment: @Ed Harper: Yes, this table contains multiple hierarchies of varying levels.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Each record contains the # of hops the ancestor and descendant nodes are apart from each other.  It also specifies the root node for that hierarchy.  It does not contain a total height of the hierarchy.  Each ancestor can have multiple descendants, but a descendant can only have one parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   descendant = @descendant
        AND hops < 
        (
        SELECT  hops
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   descendant = @descendant
                AND ancestor = @ancestor
        )
```

This will automatically take care of cases when `@ancestor` is not really a `@descendant`'s ancestor.

Create an index on `(descendant, hops)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select h1.descendant intermediate_node
from hierarchy h0 
join hierarchy h1 
  on h0.ancestor = h1.ancestor 
 and h0.hops > h1.hops  -- redundant condition, but may improve performance
join hierarchy h2
  on h1.ancestor = h2.ancestor 
 and h0.descendant = h2.descendant
where h0.ancestor = :ancestor and h0.descendant = :descendant
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   distinct ancestor 
FROM 
   hierarchy 
WHERE descendant = :1 AND 
      ancestor IN (
                    SELECT 
                       distinct descendant 
                    FROM 
                       hierarchy WHERE ancestor = :2
                  )
```